# Server configuration issue: Wordpress won't display posts after migration

Tags: mysql, linux, wordpress, apache, ubuntu

I have just finished migrating a WordPress website to a freshly setup Linode, using the duplicator plugin, however, it seems that WordPress can't connect to the database properly as it doesn't display any posts or allow admin login despite using correct credentials.

I have tested the duplicator plugin locally using MAMP and everything worked perfectly. The posts displayed correctly and I was able to log-in. 
I dont think this is the duplicator plugin. But rather it is the server being misconfigured.

I've followed this tutorial to setup the necessary permissions and create a database [Linnode tutoral](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/cms/how-to-install-and-configure-wordpress/)

The only difference is that I used Ubuntu 16.04 and used duplicator to setup the database.

Checking the database seems to have been duplicated correctly as all the tables and data are present. It seems they are just not being read.

What other server configuration issues may I be missing here?

Update:
Get the following error log from the duplicator plugin:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_posts` VALUES("138", "2"...]
**ERROR** database error write 'Table 'roses.wp_posts' doesn't exist' - [sql=INSERT INTO `wp_posts` VALUES("139", "2", "2014-12-12 11:13:53", "2014-12-1...]
**ERROR** database error write 'Table 'roses.wp_posts' doesn't exist' - [sql=INSERT INTO `wp_posts` VALUES("140", "2", "2014-12-12 23:22:14", "2014-12-1...]
**ERROR** database error write 'Table 'roses.wp_posts' doesn't exist' - [sql=INSERT INTO `wp_posts` VALUES("141", "2", "2014-12-12 23:22:14", "2014-12-1...]
**ERROR** database error write 'Table 'roses.wp_posts' doesn't exist' - [sql=INSERT INTO `wp_posts` VALUES("4", "3", "2014-11-10 21:35:15", "2014-11-10 ...]
**ERROR** database error write 'Table 'roses.wp_posts' doesn't exist' - [sql=INSERT INTO `wp_posts` VALUES("5", "3", "2014-11-10 21:35:21", "2014-11-10 ...]
**ERROR** database error write 'Table 'roses.wp_posts' doesn't exist' - [sql=INSERT INTO `wp_posts` VALUES("190", "2", "2014-12-19 14:48:05", "2014-12-1...]
**ERROR** database error write 'Table 'roses.wp_posts' doesn't exist' - [sql=INSERT INTO `wp_posts` VALUES("184", "2", "2014-12-19 01:15:23", "2014-12-1...]
```

Comment: Your question is pretty undefined. Cause there are many thing which can go wrong on setting up the server. By the way my suggestion will be have a look on the database permissions again to see if anything is wrong with the permissions or not. Hope that will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes I agree, I've posted the error log from duplicator above in an update

Comment: Does the `roses` database exist on your new server? Is it mentioned in your `wp_config.php` file in the `DB_NAME` setting? Are the other settings in that file correct? Duplicator requires that file to be rigged properly.

Comment: Evidently Table 'roses.wp_posts' doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue, seems the issue was caused by duplicator and can be overcome by editing the database file within the archive and inserting on the first line:
SET SESSION sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'; 
saving, compressing and re-uploading